# Building my web project on Visual Studio for Mac does not launch the browser

Tags: visual-studio

[image: The problem screeenshot]

Any advice? I cant seem to change the device to web, and no simulators seem to be available. Do I need to download something?

I tried to modify the build and run configurations, but it does not have a web option?

Configuration screen for overall solution
[image: Configuration screen for overall solution screenshot]

Configuration screen for web portion of the solution
[image: Configuration screen for web portion of the solution screenshot]